# Cross Compiling Linux Kernel 2.6.8 including TP-Link wifi module for ARM920T

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cross-platform, embedded-linux

I wish to integrate Wifi module on my ARM920T having **Linux Kernel 2.6.8.1**.

I am presently working on my workstation which is a x86 system with kernel version **4.2.0-27-generic**. I bought a TP-Link wifi module **(TL-WN725N_V2_150911)** and downloaded wifi driver from their official website http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN725N.html#Driver for compatible OS **Linux (kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.19.3)**.

I was successfully able to install the module on my workstation and even got my wireless network working. I now need to port it on my target device of which I am provided the **toolchain**.

I have an idea of cross-compilation but not sure how new modules are integrated into the new kernel. Or may be silly doubts such as my workstation running a relatively new kernel would effect my development of modules for old kernel? Relatively new to Embedded Development, any guidance would be a pretty good learning experience.

Comment: Just try to cross-compile. Unless someone has tried to use exactly this driver, we can only guess whether it will be successfully built and work on your machine. Asking for `the guidance from experts` is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - I am working on a workstation having kernel version 4.2 while compiling kernel module for 2.6.8. Can I still copy the .config file ?

Comment: It is very unlikely. 4.2 differs from 2.6.8 a lot.

Comment: So the first step would be to get my workstation running on the same/similar(2.X) kernel ?

Comment: Yes, it could be good for begin with your task.

Comment: thanks @Tsyvarev :)

Comment: Perhaps better to upgrade kernel in the first place on your ARM board.